# Веб-сервис поиска школ

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба

Привет.
У меня встала задача найти какой-нибудь `web-service`, возвращающий штаты, по ним города, по ним, школы.

Если кто сталкивался с такой задачей, поделитесь ссылкой, пожалуйста.

Грубо говоря, нужен сервис, который бы делал вот [это](http://nces.ed.gov/globallocator/).

Спасибо.

Comment: У этого сервиса есть огромная база данных по всем школам и университетам.

Comment: Парсить результаты не судьба?

Comment: Держу это в уме, пока окончательно не уверюсь, что таких бесплатных сервисов нет.

Comment: Ссылка не работает